# SQL cannot select rows with special characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run a query that goes like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [name] 
FROM [mpnew].[dbo].[arts] 
WHERE [grupa] = 'NAMJEŠTAJ'
```

SQL returns 0 rows even though i only have 1 row in my whole table and that row has a `[grupa] = 'NAMJEŠTAJ'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unicode literal strings need to be prefixed with `N`:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [name] 
FROM [mpnew].[dbo].[arts] 
WHERE [grupa] = N'NAMJEŠTAJ'
                ^
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. But is there no other way? I mean, in mysql i can just search for any string. Can i configure SQL to accept literal strings? Because i'm trying to query an access database that is acting like a front end for SQL @Mitch Wheat

Comment: "But is there no other way?"- not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Would it mean anything if i'd change nvarchar to varchar on columns that i want to filter?

Comment: if you change the columns to varchar you won't be able to store unicode strings in them.